# SIM Card emulator devices and applications to do everything a cell phone can

Tags: mobile-phone, desktop-computer, gsm

I'm just a bit curious to know ( and would love to try ) if it's possible to use computer as a cell phone.

To achieve this, one would probably need a way to interact with a SIM card. And perhaps a radio receiver/transmitter.

Is this possible? Are there any applications which do this or something similar? A bit of googling landed me on the [Gammu](http://wammu.eu/) homepage.

Thank you,all!

Comment: why is this off-topic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need hardware and software to do that.

For hardware, you could use a 3G Dongle like [Huawei's](http://www.3gmodem.com.hk/Huawei.html) or a phone and USB connectors. Personally I'd go for the USB dongles. They're made for 3G but you could also use them as GSM modems. They have a slot for your SIM card.

The 3G dongles usually have their own dashboard software that'll allow it to interact with your PC. You could also try [FrontLineSMS](http://www.frontlinesms.com/) as your interface. You could also write your own app using Gammu.